# InvocationRequest.setInteractive() does not exist in maven-invoker-3.0.1

Tags: java, maven, maven-invoker-plugin

InvocationRequest.setInteractive() is removed in newer versions of maven invoker API, and it is not available after version 2.1.1
is there any alternative for that? 
how we can disable interactive mode now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into the JavaDoc: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/InvocationRequest.html

See `setBatchMode` ... also on the main page might be hint https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/